How can I generate a random number within a function and use the result repeatedly in the same function?
I want to write a function that will randomly select an element in a list of arbitrary length and operate on it. For example, if I have
L = RandomInteger[100, {10}]

and want to reduce the value of a random element by 1, I can do this with e.g.
R = RandomInteger[{1, Length[L]}]
F[L_, R_] := ReplacePart[L, R -> L[[R]] - 1]
F[L, R] 

But if I include the random number (RN) generation in the function like this
F = ReplacePart[#,RandomInteger[{1,Length[#]}] -> #[[RandomInteger[{1, Length[#]}]]]- 1] &
F[L]

it generates two different RNs and so doesn't work as intended. Is there some way to generate a RN within the function and then use the result repeatedly within the same function?

You have to generate your random index only once, for example using With (or Module):
F = With[{ind = RandomInteger[{1, Length[#]}]}, 
 ReplacePart[#, ind -> #[[ind]] - 1]] &

